# drawing on image not zooming with iamge

Tags: java, android-studio

I am developing an android coloring app, in which user can fill color on image bitmap. i want to implement zoom feature on image and drawing. What i have done is that, image is zooming perfectly but drawing on it not zooming.

What i want is this:

1. if i zoom, drawing and image should be zoomed togather.
2. i want to draw after zooming on zoomed image at right coordinates.

below is my code.Thanks in Advance

**Zoom And Draw Activity Code:**

```
 public class PinchZoomPan extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {

//veriable for drawing
public int widthd;
public  int heightd;
boolean isEraser=false;
private Path drawPath;
private Paint drawPaint;
private Paint canvasPaint;
private Canvas drawCanvas;
private Bitmap canvasBitmap;
private int paintColor = Color.RED;


//////////////////////////

// veriable for zooming
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
boolean zoomEnabled = true;
static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
static final int CLICK = 3;
int mode = NONE;

PointF last = new PointF();
PointF start = new PointF();
float minScale = 1f;
float maxScale = 4f;
float[] m;

float redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace;
float width, height;
float saveScale = 1f;
float right, bottom, origWidth, origHeight, bmWidth, bmHeight;

ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
Context context;

public PinchZoomPan(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setupDrawing();
}

public PinchZoomPan(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
    super(context, attr);
    super.setClickable(true);
    this.context = context;
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    matrix.setTranslate(1f, 1f);
    m = new float[9];
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
    setupDrawing();

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {


        if (zoomEnabled) {

            mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        matrix.getValues(m);
        float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
        float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
        PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            //when one finger is touching
            //set the mode to DRAG
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                last.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                start.set(last);
                mode = DRAG;
                break;
            //when two fingers are touching
            //set the mode to ZOOM
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                last.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                start.set(last);
                mode = ZOOM;
                break;
            //when a finger moves
            //If mode is applicable move image
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                //if the mode is ZOOM or
                //if the mode is DRAG and already zoomed
                if (mode == ZOOM || (mode == DRAG && saveScale > minScale)) {
                    float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;// x difference
                    float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;// y difference
                    float scaleWidth = Math.round(origWidth * saveScale);// width after applying current scale
                    float scaleHeight = Math.round(origHeight * saveScale);// height after applying current scale
                    //if scaleWidth is smaller than the views width
                    //in other words if the image width fits in the view
                    //limit left and right movement
                    if (scaleWidth < width) {
                        deltaX = 0;
                        if (y + deltaY > 0)
                            deltaY = -y;
                        else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)
                            deltaY = -(y + bottom);
                    }
                    //if scaleHeight is smaller than the views height
                    //in other words if the image height fits in the view
                    //limit up and down movement
                    else if (scaleHeight < height) {
                        deltaY = 0;
                        if (x + deltaX > 0)
                            deltaX = -x;
                        else if (x + deltaX < -right)
                            deltaX = -(x + right);
                    }
                    //if the image doesn't fit in the width or height
                    //limit both up and down and left and right
                    else {
                        if (x + deltaX > 0)
                            deltaX = -x;
                        else if (x + deltaX < -right)
                            deltaX = -(x + right);

                        if (y + deltaY > 0)
                            deltaY = -y;
                        else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)
                            deltaY = -(y + bottom);
                    }
                    //move the image with the matrix
                    matrix.postTranslate(deltaX, deltaY);
                    //set the last touch location to the current
                    last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                }
                break;
            //first finger is lifted
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                    performClick();
                break;
            // second finger is lifted
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                break;
        }
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
        invalidate();
        return true;
    } else {

            float touchX = event.getX();
            float touchY = event.getY();
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    if(isEraser) {
                        drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
                        drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
                        drawPath.reset();
                        drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
                    } else {
                        drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
                    drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
                    drawPath = new Path();
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }

            invalidate();
            return true;
    }
}

public void setZoomEnabled(boolean b) {
    this.zoomEnabled = b;
}


@Override
public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
    super.setImageBitmap(bm);
    bmWidth = bm.getWidth();
    bmHeight = bm.getHeight();
}

public void setMaxZoom(float x) {
    maxScale = x;
}

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mode = ZOOM;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
        float origScale = saveScale;
        saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
        if (saveScale > maxScale) {
            saveScale = maxScale;
            mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
        } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
            saveScale = minScale;
            mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
        }
        right = width * saveScale - width - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
        bottom = height * saveScale - height - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
        if (origWidth * saveScale <= width || origHeight * saveScale <= height) {
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, width / 2, height / 2);
            if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                matrix.getValues(m);
                float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                    if (Math.round(origWidth * saveScale) < width) {
                        if (y < -bottom)
                            matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
                        else if (y > 0)
                            matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
                    } else {
                        if (x < -right)
                            matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
                        else if (x > 0)
                            matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());
            matrix.getValues(m);
            float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
            float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
            if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                if (x < -right)
                    matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
                else if (x > 0)
                    matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
                if (y < -bottom)
                    matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
                else if (y > 0)
                    matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    //Fit to screen.
    float scale;
    float scaleX = width / bmWidth;
    float scaleY = height / bmHeight;
    scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
    matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    saveScale = 1f;

    // Center the image
    redundantYSpace = height - (scale * bmHeight);
    redundantXSpace = width - (scale * bmWidth);
    redundantYSpace /= 2;
    redundantXSpace /= 2;

    matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

    origWidth = width - 2 * redundantXSpace;
    origHeight = height - 2 * redundantYSpace;
    right = width * saveScale - width - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
    bottom = height * saveScale - height - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
}
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    this.heightd = h;
    this.widthd= w;
    canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
}
private void setupDrawing() {
    drawPath = new Path();
    drawPaint = new Paint();
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
    drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    drawPaint.setDither(true);
    drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(15);
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save();
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
    invalidate();
}
}
```

**Main Activity**

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

PinchZoomPan pinchZoomPan;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    pinchZoomPan = new PinchZoomPan(this);
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);

    pinchZoomPan =  findViewById(R.id.drawble_view);

    Bitmap bmp = getBitmapFromVectorDrawable(this,R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);

    Bitmap alteredBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), bmp.getConfig());
    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(alteredBmp);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, paint);
    pinchZoomPan.setImageBitmap(alteredBmp);

    final Button paintBtn =  findViewById(R.id.enable_zoom);
    paintBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View button) {
            if (paintBtn.getText().toString() =="disable zoom"){
                pinchZoomPan.setZoomEnabled(false);
                paintBtn.setText("enable zoom");
            }
            else {
                pinchZoomPan.setZoomEnabled(true);
                paintBtn.setText("disable zoom");
            }
        }
    });

}

     public static Bitmap getBitmapFromVectorDrawable(Context context, int drawableId) {
    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableId);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        drawable = (DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable)).mutate();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
        drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}

}
```

Comment: Have a look at the [`Path#transform()` methods](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html). You already have the `Matrix`, so scaling the `Path`s should be trivial, with those.

Comment: i am newbie developer, can you suggest me, what should i use ? ,